# Cron fails with exit status 127

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I'm trying to get my crontab to run a few rake tasks for a rails app, but it seems to always exit with the status of 127, in my syslog it look like this:

```
Jun  7 05:10:01 ip-10-170-122-226 CRON[15664]: (deploy) CMD (cd /home/deploy/apps/dashboard/current && bundle exec rake some:task
Jun  7 05:10:01 ip-10-170-122-226 CRON[15662]: (CRON) error (grandchild #15664 failed with exit status 127)
```

It seems that 127 is like "command not found error" or something, so I've used the full paths to the bins even so like bundle was `/usr/local/bin/bundle`, The task runs fine outside of cron just running it in shell.

My crontab is simplily just:

```
*/10 * * * * cd /home/deploy/apps/dashboard/current && bundle exec rake some:task
```

Does maybe my crontab need `#!/usr/bin` or something at the top?

---

**update**

To just test it, it does seem to run this just fine:

```
*/1 * * * *  /usr/bin/touch /home/deploy/cron-test.txt
```

So that leads me to think its like a PATH varible thing, but I don't know how to get the right path vars in there, any thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Exit status 127 is set by bash when it can not find the command (see [Advanced Bash Scripting](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html)).
To make the debugging easier, you should put all the stuff in a script. Make sure that the script is executable and starts with the interpreter name and path:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /.../ &&  next_command
```

You should have the crontab line similar to:

```
*/10 * * * * cd /home/deploy/apps/dashboard/current && /PATH_TO/bundle exec rake some:task
```

or set the PATH variable in crontab:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/PATH_TO_bundle
*/10 * * * * cd /home/deploy/apps/dashboard/current && /PATH_TO/bundle exec rake some:task
```

Comment: crontab commands are executed by `/bin/sh` or by shell specified in the `SHELL` variable, so it is OK to use 'cd', shell redirection, variable expansion, conditions etc. in crontabs.

Answer (score 1):

See [`man 5 crontab`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man5/crontab.5.html) how to setup PATH for your cron jobs.

Comment: We try and avoid pointing people straight to a man page. You should answer the question and point to the man page for further reading.

Comment: well, regardless it was my Path vars, I'm not sure if this is the best route to take but what I did was just set copy my PATH var string from my env, and paste it the same to the top of the crontab file, is there a way for it to get pulled in the same as my ENV without having to paste it in? Otherwise if I change my ENV path vars I'll have to make sure my crontab is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1760488 perhaps this will point you in the right direction.

Usually what I do with cron jobs is to create a script file, test the script and then place the script in the cron.

Hope that this helps.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.